# Changing cells of a google sheet file through another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a big google sheet file with more thousand rows.

**My goal is to create another smaller spreadsheet which imports a given line from the big database** (just for show, I don't want to edit it oruse it) **and after that I'd like to add some data to that given line.**

I was able to do it with `IMPORTRANGE` function, but after I change to another row, the other rows I edited before don't keep the information I entered.

Also, I can't use my sheet to select a row in the big database and add a permanent data to it.

**Do you have any idea how could I solve this problem?** (`Google script` would be fine too, I really have no idea how to do this).

Thanks

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I get the elements of the database with `query` and use another to give the data back. However, it would be better if I could edit the elements in the same cell where I import them to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Copy Selected Row

**From one spreadsheet to another.**

```
function copySelectedRow(){
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss1.getSheetByName('Data');//Change data to the name of the sheet that you wish to copy from in ss1
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(sh1.getActiveCell().getRow(),1,1,sh1.getLastColumn());//Select a cell in the row that you wish to copy and then run this function.
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID of Spreadsheet Copying To');
  var sh2=ss2.getSheetByName('Data');//Change data to the name of the sheet that you wish to copy to in ss2
  sh2.appendRow(vA1[0]);
}
```